# Hide URL path EG /w/ with PHP or htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a **pesky** Wordpress site, installed in a directory called **/w/** -- in which cannot be rebuilt or migrated to a different location --  *YES*, I know basically what I am asking and seeking is a hack, but that is all time affords and is actually something I'm curious about anyway.

If website is **`http://www.example.com/w/`** -- how can I either **a.)** alter / add to the Wordpress default htaccess file or **b.)** maybe add something in PHP to the functions file? Or a anything else similar to uploading a script or PHP snippet to the server? - **to remove or hide the /w/**?

*Problem is -- before you get all http://codex.wordpress.org/ on me; this particular website has so many customizations, plugins, etc -- that most options listed there or elsewhere cause more problems (already tried several, took hours to revert back), because it just moves part of the website causing more issues in the long run -- so it's either this hack or a complete re installation rebuild, which I can't do due time.*

**Update - Cue Violin, nothing works**

---

Tried @David's technique by creating new `.htaccess` file in root directory behind /w/ and nothing occurred, page down in Chrome, Firefox reports 'Server attempting to redirect in a way which will never complete')

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/w/(.*)$ http://www.tonsofbeers.com/$1
```

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: This is a very simple one-line htaccess rewrite rule: rewrite any url's that don't start with `/w/` to add this `/w/` to the beginning.  Yet, depending on how the site code is written, this may not work, for example, if some files rely on their path to find other resources.

Comment: Thanks Aleks, this is what I thought, though I am not sure how to incorporate this technique to the WP htaccess file, any pointers; where I can find this kind of snippet WP friendly to give it a try?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about RedirectMatch?

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/w/$ http://www.tonsofbeers.com/
```

EDIT:

If you want to redirect all files, not just the root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/w/(.*)$ http://www.tonsofbeers.com/$1
```

EDIT 2:

Or using rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^w/(.*)$ http://www.tonsofbeers.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That will not redirect any files inside the `/w/` directory - only the root itself.

Comment: Hey @David thanks a bunch man for the input, this is exactly the method I'm trying to get working; I just tried popping this line of code in the wordpress htaccess file (which is in /w/) and pushed it back to the server and it didn't work and said failed redirect -- should I create a new htaccess file in the root with only this line of code?

Comment: Yes, put this in the root .htaccess file.

Comment: @David if you meant that last edit by itself, nope - that upload actually seemed to not do anything or affect the site at all

Comment: Just curious for whoever downvoted. Why the downvote? This is usually the right solution in most cases.